# get number day of month without Friday

Tags: php, date

I need to get the number of days in a month, but without for example Fridays.

```
$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, 2012);
```

Here I can get the total number of days, but I need to substract Fridays from the count. How do I do it?

Comment: that's obviously number of days in a month minus the number of fridays in that month :D

Comment: i thing it can do any ting by using date() function but how ? i dont Know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a handy function [here](http://markmail.org/message/ogwedc3yaxtth54r):

```
function num_days ($day, $month, $year) { 
    $day_array = array("Mon" => "Monday", "Tue" => "Tuesday", "Wed" => "Wednesday", "Thu" => "Thursday", "Fri" => "Friday", "Sat" => "Saturday", "Sun" => "Sunday");

    $month_array = array(1 => "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    /* * Check our arguments are valid. */

    /* * $day must be either a full day string or the 3 letter abbreviation. */ 
    if (!(in_array($day, $day_array) || array_key_exists($day, $day_array))) { 
        return 0; 
    }

    /* * $month must be either a full month name or its 3 letter abrreviation */ 
    if (($mth = array_search(substr($month,0,3), $month_array)) <= 0) { 
        return 0; 
    }

    /* * Now fetch the previous $day of $month+1 in $year; * this will give us the last $day of $month. */

    /* * Calculate the timestamp of the 01/$mth+1/$year. */ 

    $time = mktime(0,0,0,$mth+1,1,$year);
    $str = strtotime("last $day", $time);

    /* * Return nth day of month. */ 

    $date = date("j", $str);

    /* * If the difference between $date1 and $date2 is 28 then * there are 5 occurences of $day in $month/$year, otherwise * there are just 4. */ 

    if ($date <= 28) { 
        return 4; 
    } else { 
        return 5; 
    } 
}
```

Usage:

`echo date('t', strtotime("$month 2012")) - num_days('Friday', $month, 2012);`

Provided `$month` is a full name of a month (not a number).

Comment: i use this function and echo this
echo date('t') - num_days('Friday',06, 2012); its echo 30 its error

Comment: `date('t')` returns the number of days for the current month. Refer to the documentation of the `date()` function, or use `cal_days_in_month()` since you seem to be familiar with it.

Comment: <?php
$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,10,2005);
echo("There was $d days in October 2005");
?>
its return number day on month , but i need number Friday on month

Comment: To get the **number of Fridays** in a month, use `num_days('Friday', month, year)`. To get the **total** number of days in a month, use `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, month, year)`. To get the **answer to your question** use `cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, month, year) - num_days('Friday', month, year)`

Comment: num_days('Friday', month, year) where the function of num_days() ??

Comment: but your answer its return 31 its error we mmust return 4 day on 06 month

Comment: Oh right. You should use names instead of numeric values. So it should be `num_days('Friday', 'June', 2012)` instead.

Comment: I believe that I gave you more than enough information to answer your question, @user1433402. Please accept the answer.

Comment: @VisioN, too bad - they've removed it. :( But I've found a solution. :)